# Change page title from plugin

Tags: plugins, title, init

Is possible to change page title on the fly from plugin?

I've try global $post, but seem like plugin runs after.

Any Ideas?

Edit:
Im writting some pages on the fly, based on same page / post, so every page show the same title.
Looking a way to do via shortcode or writting my own plugin/function

Comment: Kindly provide more context to the problem. How and where is the post title being displayed/used?

Comment: Ok. The question was _HOW_ do you show the title. The Edit so far isn't really helpful, as it doesn't add real detail or does show us some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a filter for that:

```
function wpse_alter_title( $title, $id )
{
    // $id = $post->ID;
    // alter the title here
    return $title;
}
```

If you want to alter the "Protected" and "Private" titles, then you need other filters:

```
// Preserve the "%s" - else the title will be removed.
function wpse_alter_protected_title_format( $title )
{
    return __( 'Protected: %s' );
}

function wpse_alter_private_title_format( $title )
{
    return __( 'Private: %s' );
}
```

Last but not least, you must add your filter callbacks early enough.

```
function wpse_load_alter_title()
{
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_alter_title', 20, 2 );
    add_filter( 'protected_title_format', 'wpse_alter_protected_title_format' );
    add_filter( 'private_title_format', 'wpse_alter_private_title_format' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_load_alter_title' );
```

Comment: This will not work if the title is echoed out directly bypassing the filters as in `echo $post->post_title`, need more heavy artillery.

Comment: Yea, you're right. But I normally simply don't care about themes that are bypassing the public API functions.

Comment: I've updated question, to be more specific :)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the context your page title is being rendered in and how the data is being fed into it.

Consider the following:

```
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
```

Solution would involve hooking to the [`the_title`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/the_title) filter and alter it in a breeze.

How about this?

```
<h2><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h2> // not nice!
```

And it's not nice due to the problems with altering it. It's hard to know how the `$post` got populated in the first place. Consider:

```
foreach( get_posts( ... ) as $post ):
    ...
```

No place to hook there, at first glance. But it can be done inside the actual posts query. Check out the [`found_posts`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/found_posts) filter.

However, consider the following:

```
$post = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT .... " );
echo "<h2>$post->post_title</h2>"
```

That's insane.

Point is, depending on your situation there's probably a good solution. Check the template file, see how the title is being rendered. Fix it to be comfortable or make your plugin work a little harder.

And you will never ever be able to alter the title via a plugin if [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is used directly to retrieve the title. Yes, I've actually seen this done. Some people go as far as hard code it in the template even. Like *front-page.php* will contain `<h2>Home</h2>` and never even use the `$post->post_title` or ever query the database.

So, depends on the context and the situation.

Comment: Good considerations +1. But, to be honest, you could write such a list about _every aspect_ of theme/plugin dev. »That's insane.« hits it completely. IMHO it's enough to consider the public API functions. If someone's doing it wrong, well then it simply won't work. :)

Comment: Thanks, I agree that using `the_title()` is usually the right way, but recognizing `ur_doing_it_wrong()` patterns is important to be able to fix things and work with them correctly. Besides, it's not always possible to fix themes due to updates, and more importantly people don't get to see the code when buying, and don't understand the horror that most of these contain. So they end up with non-flexible themes, which don't even give them the chance to alter the title. Sad. But workable. :)

Comment: And exactly that thoughts have made me +1-ing it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm building a plugin that is heavily reliant on a front end shortcode.  This shortcode is responsible for gathering data which I need to use in the page tab `<title>` tag.  Using a shortcode made it difficult to tie in with the wordpress hooks and filters so I ended up using JavaScript to sort out the page tab title.

Easily done like this:

```
var newTitle = document.createElement("title")
newTitle.innerText = "New tab title here"
window.onload = function() {  // only add this to the DOM after it has finished loading
    document.head.prepend(newTitle)
}
```

And to be really good I also tidied up the DOM by removing any other `<title>` elements:

```
var newTitle = document.createElement("title")
newTitle.innerText = "New tab title here"
window.onload = function() {  // only add this to the DOM after it has finished loading
    let allTitles = document.getElementsByTagName("title"); 
    for (let i=0; i<allTitles.length; i++ ) { // loop through all <title> elements
        allTitles[i].remove() // ... and remove them
    }
    document.head.prepend(newTitle)
}
```

I actually echoed this out in PHP which made it simpler to add my PHP variables into the mix:

```
<?php
$newtitle = "New Tab Title Here";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    var newTitle = document.createElement("title")
    newTitle.innerText = "' . $newtitle . '"
    window.onload = function() {
        let allTitles = document.getElementsByTagName("title"); 
        for (let i=0; i<allTitles.length; i++ ) {
            allTitles[i].remove()
        }
        document.head.prepend(newTitle)
    }
    </script>';
?>
```

Hope this helps someone :)